# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Error: Record Not Found for Deletion of Object with Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following structure in my app:

```
resources :workouts do
  resources :exercises
end
```

A workout `has_many` exercises. I have it displayed so that on the `workouts#show` page there is a link to the `exercises#index` page to add/edit the exercises that belong to that workout. On the `exercises#index` page the list of exercises populates properly, but when I try to delete an exercise it gives me this error: `Couldn't find Exercise with 'id'=10 [WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?]`

My `exercises#index` page is:

```
<div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1" style="margin-top: 100px">
  <div class="opaque-card md-well well">
    <h1>Current Exercises:</h1>
      <% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
        <p><%= exercise.name %> (<%= link_to "Delete #{exercise.name}", workout_exercise_path(@workout, exercise), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>)</p>
      <% end %>
    <h1>Add New Exercises:</h1>
      <%= render 'exercises/form' %>
  </div> <!-- opaque card -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

My corresponding `routes` are:

```
       workout_exercises GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)          exercises#index
                         POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)          exercises#create
    new_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/new(.:format)      exercises#new
   edit_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id/edit(.:format) exercises#edit
        workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)      exercises#show
                         PATCH  /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)      exercises#update
                         PUT    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)      exercises#update
                         DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)      exercises#destroy
                workouts GET    /workouts(.:format)                                workouts#index
                         POST   /workouts(.:format)                                workouts#create
             new_workout GET    /workouts/new(.:format)                            workouts#new
            edit_workout GET    /workouts/:id/edit(.:format)                       workouts#edit
                 workout GET    /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#show
                         PATCH  /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#update
                         PUT    /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#update
                         DELETE /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#destroy
```

And here is my `exercises_controller.rb`:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
      @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
      @exercise = Exercise.new
      @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
  end

  def create
  #  require 'pry' ; binding.pry
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.build(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise created successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "The exercise failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    exercise.user = current_user
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])

    if exercise.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
      params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps, :workout_id)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

I have already tried un-nesting the routes and that causes far more errors than it resolves. Can anyone see why I'm getting this error or how to fix it?

ADDED: Here are the `params` from my server log from before the error:

```
Started DELETE "/workouts/d/exercises/10" for ::1 at 2016-06-05 10:39:29 -0700
Processing by ExercisesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xAWbVPHRNJeGSWhThaAMDf/FUYXav4WXrMBnjoX7s3g+gTQEVo0r9wIhSxIB+yH8sdwhcxfDZV9SinaLSUEiMA==", "workout_id"=>"d", "id"=>"10"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Workout Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "workouts".* FROM "workouts" WHERE "workouts"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "workouts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "d"]]
  Exercise Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ? AND "exercises"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["workout_id", 4], ["id", 10]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Exercise with 'id'=10 [WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?]:
```

ADDED: Form referenced in `exercises#index`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
    <%= form_for [@workout, @exercise] do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :workout_id, value: @workout.id %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter exercise name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_seconds, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_seconds, class: 'check_box' %> Report seconds?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_reps, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_reps, class: 'check_box' %> Report reps?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_weight, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_weight, class: 'check_box' %> Report weight?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Create Exercise", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the `params` that appear in the server log when perform this action?

Comment: @Pavan, I updated the question to include this info.

Comment: Your `params` looks fine to me. Do you have an `exercise` record with `id = 10` in the table?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the console.

Comment: And also check the `workout_id` for that record is equal to 4 or not?

Comment: Here's the whole record:   `irb(main):022:0> Exercise.where(id: 10)
  Exercise Load (5.2ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Exercise id: 10, name: "Again?", seconds: nil, weight: nil, reps: nil, workout_id: 1, user_id: 1, needs_seconds: 0, needs_weight: 0, needs_reps: 1, created_at: "2016-06-03 18:33:50", updated_at: "2016-06-03 18:33:50">]>`

Comment: The `workout_id` for that record is `1` not `4`, so rails unable to find the record with that combination. I guess the problem lies with this line `@workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])`. Try inspecting it as @Kumar Abinash pointed out.

Comment: As I mentioned below, the `@workout` comes back just fine in the console.  The workout comes back with `id: 4`, the error message is talking about the exercise with an id = 10.

Comment: And `exercise` comes back as `nil` in the error message console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])` is not finding any records. Can you make sure it does find something, by printing it out to the rails console,

```
@workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])

p "Workout: ", @workout
p "Exercise: ", exercise #they should print the found object or nil in your rails server console
```

If you see `nil` I'd say finding via friendly id is causing the problem.

> Update:

My bad. I hadn't seen. So see when you're building your exercise you're passing `exercise_params`, and if you note exercise_params also has a `workout_id` which must be passed `nil` so it rewrites the value of `workout_id` in your newly created `exercise`. Just get rid of `workout_id` from your `exercise` params. And try creating a few more exersize and test again for those.

Comment: Please let me know what does it print.

Comment: When I type in `@workout` in the error message console it does come up with `>> @workout
=> #<Workout id: 4, name: "Sample Workout", workout_type: "Abs", teaser: "Teaser goes here.  A witty one, preferably", description: "And then here's the even longer description.  Oh h...", trainer: nil, user_id: 1, slug: "d", video: "videolink", difficulty: "Easy Peasy", created_at: "2016-06-03 00:33:01", updated_at: "2016-06-03 23:25:06">`

Comment: And what about `exercise`? Does it get printed?

Comment: Nope. Just `exercise` is `nil`.

Comment: Can you do this in your rails console? `ex = Exercise.where(workout_id: 4)`. We know your workouts id is 4 when it printed out in the console. So we need to make sure it shows exercises related to your workout. Let me know if that does fetch any records.

Comment: `irb(main):025:0> ex = Exercise.where(workout_id: 4)
  Exercise Load (8.2ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?  [["workout_id", 4]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Liz that none of your exercises are related to your workouts. Can you show me your `exercise#index`'s code.

Comment: I'd guess while creating exercises you're not associating them with workouts. So exercise's `workout_id` is being saved `nil`

Comment: The `exercises#index` is shown above (at the beginning of the question), as  is the `exercises_controller`. Where else would I look to figure out if that's the case?

Comment: I also added the `exercises/_form` partial referenced on the `exercises#index` page where the exercises are initially created.

Comment: YESSSS!  That one worked!  So do I just clear the others using the console since they were created wrong?

Comment: I'm glad it worked @Liz. Yes I think you should clear all the exercises only. `Exercise.destory_all`.

Comment: Oops. use `delete_all`

Comment: Tried both and they still exist.

Comment: I don't know. That's a straightforward way. Maybe you purge everything, since everything is test data. :) One more update is coming for your code. Gimme a min.

Comment: Thank you.  Also, is the change @Pavan suggested above compatible with these changes?

Comment: Yes. In fact I don't think you need to do this even `@workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])`. You are directly finding exercise by its id and deleting it, according to pavan's code.

Comment: Ah...so remove that, but JUST for the destroy method?

Comment: Yes. Only for destroy.

Comment: The deletion actually didn't work with that line deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Exercise with 'id'=10
>   [WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?]

There are two problems in your code. First the `@exercises` variable holds ***all the exercises records*** not the ***@workout's exercises***. Second, with the `exercise` variable you are trying to find that ***workout's exercise*** with the `params[:id]` which is actually the `id` of one of the `@exercises` looped in the view. So Rails unable to find the record with the ***combination(:workout_id & :id)***, so is the error.

***Solution***

Change `exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])` to `exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])` in the `destroy` method.

```
def destroy
  @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
  exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])

  if exercise.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
    redirect_to [@workout]
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
    redirect_to [@workout]
  end
end
```

Comment: Should I still make this change given what we figured out was wrong below (I had been creating a new, blank `workout_id` in my exercise `params`)?

Comment: @Liz That is the main problem. You are creating the exercises wrongly. Clean all the existing exercises and try creating with the changes what Kumar Abinash said. But my solution also works as you are passing the independent exercises objects, not the workout's exercises.

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I'm sure this would have created problems later on.